# jest process.cwd() to get the test file directory

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

In my current code, I use `process.cwd()` to get the current working directory and then load some file (like config file).

Below I will show the concept of my code and how I test it.

This is the directory structure:

```
├── index.js
└── test
    ├── index.test.js
    └── config.js
```

**index.js**

```
const readRootConfig = function() {
  const dir = process.cwd();
  console.log(dir); // show the working dir
  const config = require(`${dir}/config.js`);
}
```

And then I use jest to test this file.

**index.test.js**

```
import readRootConfig '../index';

it('test config', () => {
  readRootConfig();
})
```

After run the test, `console` of dir is `./` (real output is absolute path, I just show the relative path in this demo)

But what I hope the output of dir is `./test`.

Is there any config to make jest use the `test file folder` to be the `process.cwd()` folder?

I am thinking one of the solution is pass `dir path` as a parameter, like:

**index.js**

```
const readRootConfig = function(dir) {
  console.log(dir); // show the working dir
  const config = require(`${dir}/config.js`);
}
```

But I am not pretty like this solution, cause this method is to adapt to the test.

So any suggestion? thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you want to make a module that can know what file required it, you can use `module.parent`. It is the module that first required this one. And then you can use `path.dirname` to get the directory of the file.

So `index.js` should be like this

```
const path = require('path')

const readRootConfig = function() {
  const dir = path.dirname(module.parent.filename)
  console.log(dir); // show the working dir
  const config = require(`${dir}/config.js`);
}
```

Comment: `module.parent` is now deprecated as of `v19.6.0`: https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#DEP0144

Answer (score 2):

`__dirname` does the trick nicely as `module.parent` is now deprecated as of Node `v19.6.0` - https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#__dirname